# Pass a list of files to perl script via pipe

Tags: linux, perl, shell, pipe

I am having a problem where my perl script will fail upon having an input piped, but works fine when I just list all the file names individually.

For reference, input of the perl script is read with while(<>).

Example:

```
script.pl file1.tag file2.tag file3.tag
```

runs fine.

But the following all fail.

```
find ./*.tag | chomp | script.pl
ls -l *.tag | perl -pe 's/\n/ /g' | script.pl
find ./*.tag | perl -pe 's/\n/ /g' | script.pl
```

I also tested dumping it into a text file and catting that into the perl:

```
cat files.text | script.pl
```

All of them fail the same way.  It is like the script is passed no input arguments and the program just finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

> The null filehandle `<>` is special [...] Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `-`, which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames.

You're not passing any command line arguments to your Perl scripts, so everything you pipe into them is read into `STDIN` instead of being treated as filenames:

```
$ echo foo > foo.txt
$ echo bar > bar.txt
$ ls | perl -e 'print "<$_>\n" while <>'
<bar.txt
>
<foo.txt
>
```

Notice that the files `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` are not actually read; all we get is the file names. If you want the files to be opened and read, you have to pass them as command line arguments or explicitly set `@ARGV`:

```
$ perl -e 'print "<$_>\n" while <>' *
<bar
>
<foo
>
```

If you have a large number of files, like you're likely to get from `find`, you should use `xargs` as [Dyno Hongjun Fu suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042777/176646).

However, you don't need `find`, `ls`, `cat`, or your Perl one-liner to run your script on all the `.tag` files in the current directory. Simply do:

```
script.pl *.tag
```

Comment: Wow way simpler than I thought.  Thanks for the complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

you need xargs, e.g.

```
 find ./ -type f -name "*.tag" | xargs -i script.pl {}
```

what is chomp?

Comment: chomp removes the trailing new line.  it was my attempt to make sure the formatting was exactly the same as my listed version (no newline at end)

Comment: basically, xargs will solve your problem. you can also try remove -i,
```find ./ -type f -name "*.tag" | xargs script.pl``` then it will feed to script.pl in a batch.